# Is it possible with camtasia quizes to choose a specific marker?

Tags: video, user-interaction, camtasia

I use quizes on media level. User chooses an answer and based on the answer I would like to show the media which depends on this answer. It means that each answer in quiz should be mapped to some marker. Can this be achieved with camtasia?

Answer (score 0):

Camtasia is a video program it does not have what you are looking for.

However what I think you are looking for is PowerPoint try asking in  tag powerpoint.